# How can I disable change in a text box by user using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show some value in text box in user interface. I have to disable the change in the textbox value ie when user  tries to change or delete the value. how can I do this using jquery?

Comment: If the user won't be able to change the value, why not use a `span` or any other non-input element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use jquery?? This would work:
`<input type="text" value="your value" disabled="disabled" />`

Comment: i am using mvc3 platform so I am not sure if it is the right way